# When parsing the constructor GQLReq of type Hasura.GraphQL.Transport.HTTP.Protocol.GQLReq expected Object but got String

Tags: flutter, hasura, built-value, chopper

I am trying to make a request to a Hasura backend using Flutter, Chopper and Built Value and I am getting the following error

```
> When parsing the constructor GQLReq of type Hasura.GraphQL.Transport.HTTP.Protocol.GQLReq expected Object but got String.,
```

Chopper service

```
@ChopperApi(baseUrl: '/v1/graphql')
abstract class PostApiService extends ChopperService {
  @Post()
  Future<Response<BuiltPost>> get(@Body() String body);

  static PostApiService create(AuthHeaderProvider authHeaderProvider) {
    final client = ChopperClient(
      baseUrl: 'https://arrivee-app-test.herokuapp.com',
      services: [
        _$PostApiService(),
      ],
      converter: BuiltValueConverter(),
      interceptors: [
        HttpLoggingInterceptor(),
     //   HeadersInterceptor({'content-type': 'application/json'}),
        HeadersInterceptor({'Authorization':'Bearer token'})
      ],
    );
    return _$PostApiService(client);
  }
}
```

I make request with the following code

```
    var request = RequestModel((b) => b
  ..query = fetchAccommodations()
  ..variables = null
  ..operationName = 'AccommodationGet');

var response = await client.get(request.toJson());
```

RequestModel

```
    abstract class RequestModel
    implements Built<RequestModel, RequestModelBuilder> {
  String get query;

  @nullable
  String get variables;

  String get operationName;

  RequestModel._();

  factory RequestModel([updates(RequestModelBuilder b)]) = _$RequestModel;

  String toJson() {
    return json
        .encode(serializers.serializeWith(RequestModel.serializer, this));
  }

  static RequestModel fromJson(String jsonString) {
    return serializers.deserializeWith(
        RequestModel.serializer, json.decode(jsonString));
  }

  static Serializer<RequestModel> get serializer => _$requestModelSerializer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Encountered the same error while trying to make a simple http POST call to Hasura in Angular Dart (no GraphQL client available).

I have found that the Json String had to be built in the following way :

```
   String query = """
      {
        account {
            id
          }
      }
    """;

    Map<String, dynamic> variables;

    if (query.trimLeft().split(' ')[0] != 'query') {
      query = 'query $docQuery';
    }

    var jsonMap = {'query': query, 'variables': variables};

    final _headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
    return _authHttpService.post(_apiUrl,
        headers: _headers, body: json.encode(jsonMap));
```

Hope it helps anyone looking for a vanilla Dart solution.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. posting here for future reference.
I let chopper do the conversion from a model to a string instead of doing it manually beforehand here 
I changed the signature of the chopper service from :

```
 @Post()
  Future<Response<BuiltPost>> get(@Body() String body);
```

to

```
@Post()
Future<Response<BuiltPost>> get(@Body() RequestModel body);
```

and calling the service from:

```
 var request = RequestModel((b) => b
  ..query = fetchAccommodations()
  ..variables = null
  ..operationName = 'AccommodationGet');

var response = await client.get(request.toJson());
```

to

```
 var request = RequestModel((b) => b
      ..query = fetchAccommodations()
      ..variables = null
      ..operationName = 'AccommodationGet');

var value = await client.get(request);
```